# How can I send articles from iOS Safari browser to my Kindle

Tags: kindle, send-to-kindle

I have extensions for Chrome and FireFox to "Send to Kindle" as listed on http://www.amazon.com/gp/sendtokindle but there is no solution for iOS Safari browser.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are just a few possibilities (which I have not tested):

- [An app that lets you push to Kindle from within Safari](http://fivefilters.org/kindle-it/)
- [A bookmarklet (JavaScript link) that lets you add a page to Kindle](http://ctrlq.org/ios/?kindle#javascript:(%28function%28%29%7Bwindow.baseUrl%3D%27http%3A//www.readability.com%27%3Bwindow.readabilityToken%3D%27%27%3Bvar%20s%3Ddocument.createElement%28%27script%27%29%3Bs.setAttribute%28%27type%27%2C%27text/javascript%27%29%3Bs.setAttribute%28%27charset%27%2C%27UTF-8%27%29%3Bs.setAttribute%28%27src%27%2CbaseUrl%2B%27/bookmarklet/send-to-kindle.js%27%29%3Bdocument.documentElement.appendChild%28s%29%3B%7D%29%28%29))
- [Another bookmarklet](https://www.readability.com/bookmarklets)

Let us know if any of these work for you!

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have only tried the http://fivefilters.org/kindle-it/ version so far and while it works perfectly, they only give you 25 credits. After those are used up you have to buy more.

Comment: Good to know. The bookmarklets may be better options, anyway, as they're just JavaScript.

Comment: I've tried the second option, which is a ctrlq.org bookmarklet and this is working great. (Thanks I've accepted this as the answer). 

It was a bit problematic to setup at first as the video on the page uses an older version of iOS. Secondly the page that actually does all the work (readability, the third option) needs your email address etc. and this page isn't mobile friendly. 

But I got there in the end. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

See [Comfy Read](http://comfyread.in). It is an iOS app + service that let's you send articles from pretty much any app in iOS that supports the standard iOS share sheet. No credits. Upfront paid.

Disclaimer: I am the Comfy Read developer.